# git hook post-receive not working

Tags: git, shell, deployment, web-deployment

I trying to deploy some PHP code to the server with Git. I am using a GoDaddy server. I have created the *bare* repository. In the `hooks` folder, I created a `post-receive` file and wrote the following code in it.

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/domain/public_html/website git checkout -f
```

I want the git repo to move the source code that I have just pushed to the website directory in `public_html`. I changed the permission to `0775`.

However, my `website` directory still remains empty. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's because you spelled "`post-recieve`" wrong?  It should be `post-receive` (note the i and e after the c).

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make.  Little things like that have caught me too. :-)

Answer (score -2):

Good point by jszakmeister. Also, the hook file has to be executable. Just do `chmod +x post-receive` for that.

Comment: The OP had already made the hook executable:  *I changed the permission to `0775`*.