# Git post-receive hook is not executed

Tags: linux, git, githooks, git-post-receive

The following `post-receive` hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "-> Post-receive test"
```

is **not executed** when pushing to my remote repository.

The remote is `ssh://user@server:2222/home/git/repo.git` (it's a VM) and works, as when I manually checkout it I see the modifications I've made.

Some additional informations ...

```
$ ls -al /home/git
drwxr-xr-x  7 git  git  4096 juin  15 15:40 repo.git

$ ls -al /home/git/repo.git/hooks
-rwxr-xr-x  1 git  git  117  juin  15 15:40 post-reveive
```

Everything seems in place and yet, when I push to the remote, there's no trace of the `post-receive` being executed:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 301 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://user@server:2222/home/git/repo.git
   6c385f4..d368bf9  master -> master
```

**Why wouldn't the `post-receive` hook be executed?**

Comment: You want `post-commit` http://git-scm.com/book/zh/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git post-receive hook not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950800/git-post-receive-hook-not-working)

Comment: @Ôrel The  `post-receive` hook is what I'm looking for, it just doesn't get executed! Got it working on another server, that's why I can't understand why it doesn't work here..

Comment: `ls` shows you named the file `post-reveive`.

Comment: @Kristján Damn man... Spent almost the day on this. Thank you. I can't face the web anymore, too much shame.

Comment: Happens to me all the time :-D

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29510830/2541573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook file is incorrectly named `post-reveive`.